# How to search for a specific string in previous changesets?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

At some point in the last few months one of the devs in our team may have removed a specific string from the code. We don't know where that string was. This now may be causing a bug.

Is it possible to search TFS history somehow to find when and where that string was removed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the [Team Foundation Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/index.htm) tool. It has a History feature [image: History Sidekick]